# BassBoost effect in android

Tags: android

I tried to implement bassboost effect in android..but there is no effect..I used the following code for bassboost effect;(I tried using global audio session id and i added permissions in manifest file)-->modify audio settings..

```
enter code here

     BassBoost boost = new BassBoost(0,mp.getAudioSessionId());
     boost.setEnabled(true);
     boost.setStrength((Short)1000);
     mp.attachAuxEffect(boost.getId());--->if i use this i'm getting(-38,0) or else no effect                         
     mp.setSendLevel(1.0f);
```

---

I used below code for bass boost effect.got media player(-38,0) error..please resolve this issue..

```
enter code here
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

 MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
 AssetFileDescriptor descriptor;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

try {
    descriptor = MainActivity.this.getAssets().openFd("Kalimba.mp3");
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    mediaplayer.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(),
              descriptor.getStartOffset(),                                 descriptor.getLength());


} catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    descriptor.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {

    e1.printStackTrace();
}

setUpBooster();

mediaplayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.start();
    }
});



  }

 public void setUpBooster() {

BassBoost booster = new BassBoost(0,0);//-->tried with sessionid also
booster.setStrength((short) 1000);
booster.setEnabled(true);
mediaplayer.attachAuxEffect(booster.getId());
mediaplayer.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);
try {
    mediaplayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();

  }

 }
```

Comment: What state is your `MediaPlayer` in when you call `attachAuxEffect`? You must - at least - have called `setDataSource` before attaching the effect. It's also a good idea to use [queryEffects](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/AudioEffect.html#queryEffects()) to make sure that the effect you want to use actually is available.

Comment: I used setDatasource..i'm trying since last 10 days..sometimes..i'm getting (-22,0)..sometimes(-38,0)..if i don't attach aux effect to media player..then there is no error..but with no effect..

Answer (score 0):

**error 38** means you are asking the `MediaPlayer to do something when in the wrong state.` You won't be `able to fathom your error just from this`.

And anytime you call `setDataSource()` on it you will need to `prepare()` it again. Think of it as loading the file, getting ready for playback.

**Edit**

> You have already attached your bassboost with your mediaplayer when it created. So remove this  `mp.attachAuxEffect(boost.getId());`